# How can I list "devices" available to Whisper AI?

Tags: gpu

Whisper AI has a command line argument `device` which you can use to specify that i should use the CPU, GPU etc. How can I list devices Whisper AI can use on a certain system? Specifically I have an AMD Radeon card on the machine I want to run Whisper AI on but no value I have tried with `device` so far has worked.

Comment: According to https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/55 these are valid values for device: cpu, cuda, ipu, xpu, mkldnn, opengl, opencl, ideep, hip, ve, ort, mps, xla, lazy, vulkan, meta, hpu, privateuseone. Not sure if this list is complete or if there are even more options.